# GUI drawing in background Thread MacOS

Tags: macos, user-interface, drawing

Is there a way to do background drawing of App in MacOS? I have 3 `NSTableViews`. With different intervals (0.5sec - 2 sec) I'm using their `reloadData` methods. I also have many other GUI elements which need to redisplay information. When GUI is redrawing app stops for the small periods of time and it's seems like "lags". It's not good(

I think what drawing in background thread will help me, but I don't know how to do this with all my App.

Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late, but hope it's still actual.
I don't know about MAC OS X, but in iOS I use viewDidAppear or ViewWillAppear, in OS X it should be similar.